# What are the differences between copy, mutableCopy and assignment？

Tags: objective-c, copy

I thought I understood the difference between copy and mutableCopy. But today I doubt about myself. I still don't understand.

```
NSArray *arrayB = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"a"];
NSArray *arrayA = [arrayB copy];
NSArray *arrayC = [arrayB mutableCopy];
NSArray *arrayD = arrayB;
```

when I make some changes to arrayA, arrayC or arrayD，will arrayB have the same change with one of changed arrayA, arrayC and arrayD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Can't modify this NOW
NSArray *arrayB = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"a"]; 

// Create another copy of Array B like XEROX. If you change in XEROX 
// it does not reflect to original Copy
NSArray *arrayA = [arrayB copy]; 

// This is a mutable copy so you can make changes in this and you have
// to change NSArray to NSMutableArray here as it the mutable copy.
NSMutableArray *arrayC = [arrayB mutableCopy]; 

// Any change made in arrayD reflect to arrayB but arrayD is NSArray
// (immutable) so you can not make any changes in arrayD
NSArray *arrayD = arrayB;
```

Hope this will help to clear the things for you.

Comment: Yes,got it. I think i understand it

Answer (score 0):

You can't make changes to arrayA, arrayB or arrayD, they are immutable (and arrayD is not a new instance, it points to the same object that arrayB does). You can only set these pointers to point to a different array. 
 If you make a change to arrayC (the only mutable instance here) then no, arrayB, which it was previously copied from, will not change.